# aws amplify Auth.SignIn() not working on production but works on local react native

Tags: authentication, graphql, aws-amplify

JavaScript Framework : React native

Amplify APIs : Authentication

Amplify Categories: auth

Describe the bug

`Auth.signIn({ username, password })`
is not getting triggered on production (expo test) `eas build --profile preview --platform android` but works perfectly on local env.
Contrariwise `Auth.signUp()` works perfectly and the user saved in dynamodb
all the packages up-to-date.

I have AmplifyService :

```
SignIn =async (username: string, password: string) => {
return await Auth.signIn({ username, password });
};

SignUpUser = async (username: string, password: string,email:string,name:string) => {
return await Auth.signUp({ username, password, attributes: { email, name } });
};
```

and in the component i call

```
const [isUserAuthenticated, setIsUserAuthenticated] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
SignUpUser();
}, []);
const SignUpUser = () => {

AmplifyService.SignIn("test", "password0")
.then(() => {
    setIsUserAuthenticated(true);
}).catch((err) => {
// if user not found in dynamoDB
AmplifyService.SignUpUser("test","password0","email@xx.xx","test").then(() => {
    AmplifyService.SignIn(username, password).then(() => 
    {
        setIsUserAuthenticated(true);
    });

  });
 });
};
```

Comment: Please add your code to allow us to further debug your issue.

Comment: @Luke, thanks for ur answer , the only code i have : 

SignIn = (username: string, password: string) => {
        return Auth.signIn({ username, password });
    };
SignIn("test","passwordTEST");

Comment: Why not at error handling?

Comment: @Luke npm install amazon-cognito-identity-js sovle the problem , thanks anyway